# biblatex - issue number of journal in date

Tags: biblatex, biber

I am building a bibliography using `biblatex` and `biber` (`\usepackage[backend=biber,minnames=2,backref,firstinits,sortcites]{biblatex}`) with a lot of cited papers. Therefore I often have the case of a journal name, volume, issue, month and year, all necessary.

Now the strange thing is, if I have a bibitem such as:

```
@article{item,
  title = {Some Nice Scientific Title},
  author = {Doe, Jane},
  journal = {Important Journal},
  volume = {50},
  issue = {20},
  pages = {1877--1879},
  year = {1984},
  month = {Jun},
  publisher = {Important Society},
  doi = {00.0000}
}
```

the bibliography looks like this:

[image: mwi output]

Can you spot it? The issue number `20` is in the brackets with the date. Now it looks like it is the day in the date.

So, how do I get around this?

Here's the full MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[backend=biber,minnames=2,backref,firstinits,sortcites]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{item.bib}
  @article{item,
    title = {Some Nice Scientific Title},
    author = {Doe, Jane},
    journal = {Important Journal},
    volume = {50},
    issue = {20},
    pages = {1877--1879},
    year = {1984},
    month = {Jun},
    publisher = {Important Society},
    doi = {00.0000}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{item.bib}

\begin{document}

\printbibliography[title = {References},heading=bibintoc]
\nocite{*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use the `number` field and not `issue`. While many journals call the 'subdivision' of a volume 'issue', `biblatex` uses `number` here.  `issue` is meant for more concrete names such as 'Summer issue'.

Comment: @moewe Huh, as simple as that... Thanks! (Maybe someone should tell the publishers who offer citation downloads...) Is this some sort of remnant from the `bibtex` past?

Comment: @Taunch - You asked, "Is this some sort of remnant from the bibtex past?" The answer is, "Almost certainly not."  Virtually all bibliography style files are programmed to recognize and process a field called `number` if it occurs in an entry of type `@article`, but hardly any of them would even know what to make of a field called `issue`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to use the `number` field and not `issue`. While many journals call the 'subdivision' of a volume 'issue', `biblatex` uses `number` here. `issue` is meant for more concrete names such as 'Summer issue'.

Refer also to [the `biblatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf), which for `issue` has to say on page 20

> This field [`issue`] is intended for journals whose individual issues
>   are identified by a designation such as ‘Spring’ or ‘Summer’ rather than the month or a number. [...]

the field `number` is characterised as (p. 21)

> The number of a journal or the volume/number of a book in a `series`.

As far as I am aware it has been this way since the good ol' BibTeX times.
Indeed [`btxdoc`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/biblio/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) (§ 3.2, p. 10) describes the `number` field as (emphasis mine)

> The number of a journal, magazine, technical report, or of a work in a
>   series. *An issue of a journal or magazine is usually identified by its volume
>   and number*; the organization that issues a technical report usually gives
>   it a number; and sometimes books are given numbers in a named series.

Some citation download tools on the web use `issue` inappropriately where `number` should be used. That is one of the reasons why you should always check downloaded entries thoroughly manually.

The following Biber sourcemap maps `issue` to `number` and then deletes it if the field only contains a number

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \step[fieldsource=issue, match=\regexp{\A[0-9]+\Z}, final]
      \step[fieldset=number, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldset=issue, null]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for "you should always check downloaded entries thoroughly manually". :-)