# Why does the issue number appear when using \citeyear with apa-syle?

Tags: biblatex, biber, apa-style

When I use `\cite` there is not only the author and the year but the issue number.

I have never observed that before. Did something changed in the biblatex-apa-style components or did I miss something?

The example produce the output

> 2017, 5

But I would expect

> 2017

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Rantanen2017,
  author       = {Rantanen, Pekka and Parkkari, Timo and Leikola, Saija and Airaksinen, Marja and Lyles, Alan},
  title        = {An In-home Advanced Robotic System to Manage Elderly Home-care Patients' Medications},
  journaltitle = {Clinical therapeutics},
  year         = {2017},
  volume       = {39},
  issue        = {5},
  pages        = {1054--1061},
  doi          = {10.1016/j.clinthera.2017.03.020},
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            style=apa,
            sortlocale=de_DE,
            language=german
        ]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{german}{german-apa}

\begin{document}
\citeyear{Rantanen2017}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `number = {5},` The subdivision of `volume` for `@article`s goes into the `number` field even though many publisher call it 'issue'.

Comment: Related https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354759/35864

Comment: Citavi-biblatex-export is the root of that problem. :)