# biblatex: separate date from issue, date behind journal title, no parentheses

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

I have my bibliography almost exactly as I want it, with one exception: I'd like the year to come after the journal title, separated by a comma, no parentheses. Right now, the issue number and year are in parentheses together. Also, the colon comes after the volume instead of after the issue, as I would like it. (I can't manually move the number from the "issue" field to the "number" field in hundreds of Bibtex entries, as suggested in another answer).

So, instead of this:[image]

I'd like this:[image]

Here's my MWE

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=numeric-comp,
giveninits=true,
maxbibnames=2,
%citestyle=nature,
sorting=none,
isbn=false,
doi=false
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname} % 1st author as lastname, comma, firstname-initials, 2nd author as firstname-initials lastname

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname} %names bold

\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}} %month not printed
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{day}} %day not printed
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{note}} %notes not printed

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1} %no quotation marks

\DeclareDelimFormat[biblist,bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space} %comma after names

\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\,} %thinspace between name initials

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}} %supresses "In:" before journal titles

\DeclareFieldFormat{titlecase}{#1} %Journal titles capitalized as given (not sentence case)

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inbook, incollection, inproceedings, misc, thesis, unpublished]
{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}} %number/issue between brackets

\DeclareFieldFormat[article, inproceedings, incollection, inbook]
{pages}{p. #1} %single p. instead of pp.

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{
    \printfield{volume}
    \printfield{number}
    \printunit{\addcolon}} %format 16(4):224--225 for articles


%year after journal title

%no parentheses around date

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@Article{Brem2002,
    author          = {Brem, Rachel B and Yvert, Gaël and Clinton, Rebecca and Kruglyak, Leonid},
    title           = {Genetic dissection of transcriptional regulation in budding yeast.},
    journal         = {Science},
    year            = {2002},
    volume          = {296},
    pages           = {752--755},
    month           = apr,
    issue           = {5568},
}

@Article{Yvert2003,
    author          = {Yvert, Gaël and Brem, Rachel B and Whittle, Jacqueline and Akey, Joshua M and Foss, Eric and Smith, Erin N and Mackelprang, Rachel and Kruglyak, Leonid},
    title           = {Trans-acting regulatory variation in Saccharomyces cerevisiae and the role of transcription factors.},
    journal         = {Nat. Genet.},
    year            = {2003},
    volume          = {35},
    pages           = {57--64},
    month           = sep,
    issue           = {1},
}

\end{filecontents}  

\begin{document}

    I'm citing \cite{Brem2002} and \cite{Yvert2003}.

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that the code as shown is not a fully compilable example document. It is missing `\end{document}` and actual body contents (a few example citations and `\printbibliography`, presumably). The question is also missing relevant example entries from `refs.bib`. If the exact contents of your bib entries are not relevant, you can use the file `biblatex-examples.bib` that is available on all systems with `biblatex`.

Comment: Sorry about that, I fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following redefinitions for `journal+issuetitle` and `volume+number+eid` are copied from the code for `biblatex-ext`. That's why they contain a few customisable macros.

Instead of using `\clearfield` to suppress month and days in the date, it should be simpler to just say `date=year,` in the load-time options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=numeric-comp,
  sorting=none,
  maxbibnames=2,
  giveninits=true,
  date=year,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
]{biblatex}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given/given-family}
\DeclareNameAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{sortname}

\DeclareNameWrapperFormat{sortname}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{author}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{editor}{sortname}
\DeclareNameWrapperAlias{translator}{sortname}

\renewrobustcmd*{\bibinitdelim}{\,}

\DeclareDelimFormat[biblist,bib]{nametitledelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}

\newcommand*{\volnumdelim}{\adddot}
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\volnumdelim}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewcommand*{\volnumdelim}{}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article, periodical]{number}{\mkbibparens{#1}}

\newcommand*{\jourdatedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\jourserdelim}{\addcomma\space}
\newcommand*{\datevolnumdelim}{\newunitpunct}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\jourdatedelim}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\setunit*{\jourserdelim}%
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\jourdatedelim}}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \setunit{\datevolnumdelim}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewcommand*{\bibpagespunct}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {\addcolon}
    {\addcomma}%
  \space
}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{
  pages = {p\adddot},
}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Sigfridsson, E. and U. Ryde, Comparison of methods for deriving atomic charges from the electrostatic potential and moments. Journal of Computational Chemistry, 1998. 19(4): p. 377–395.]

Since your `.bib` file uses `issue` where `number` would be more appropriate you can fix this on the fly with a Biber source map: [biblatex - issue number of journal in date](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/354759/35864).